# Applying elements to object vs applying them to object's symbol name

Tags: kdb

I saw a technique to access directory elements by its symbol rather then its name (see `q.k`):

```
`.q `svar`sdev`scov`med / instead of .q `svar`sdev`scov`med
```

Why and when this approach is useful?

---

Also for some reason the behaviour is reversed compared to the `@` apply:

```
q)l:til 5
q)`l[2 3]: 20 30 / 'assign, `l not changed
/ (upd: `l is not just a symbol here, it is exactly refers to a list: `l[2 3] gets l elements)
q)l[2 3]: 21 31; l / l changed
0 1 21 31 4
```

But when we use `@` apply syntax, the result is reversed:

```
q)@[l;2 3;:;22 32]; l / l not changed
0 1 21 31 4
q)@[`l;2 3;:;23 33]; l / `l changed
0 1 23 33 4
```

---

upd:
Applying indexes to a symbol does no work in shakti, looks like this idea hadn't withstand the test of time.

Answer (score 4):

By directory, I think you mean dictionary as this is the data structure which is returned when you call `.q`.

You can access dictionary elements a number of ways:

```
q)d:`a`b`c!1 2 3
q)d
a| 1
b| 2
c| 3
q)d`a
1
q)`d `a
1
q)d[`a]
1
q)@[d;`a]
1
q)@[`d;`a]
1
q) / etc ...
```

which are all [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar#:%7E:text=In%20computer%20science%2C%20syntactic%20sugar,style%20that%20some%20may%20prefer.) for each other, it just depends which you prefer (or what the situation dictates is better).

In the code below,

```
q)`l[2 3]:20 30
'assign
  [0]  `l[2 3]:20 30
```

`` `l `` is simply the symbol `` `l ``, not a reference to the list `l`, which is why you get an assign error.

The `@` operator is slightly different,

```
q)@[l;0;:;20]
20 1 2 3 4
q)l
0 1 2 3 4
q) / -vs-
q)@[`l;0;:;20]
`l
q)l
20 1 2 3 4
```

adding the backtick to `l` is telling q that you want to update `l` not just apply the operation to the list and return the result.